# Using a wildcard to open an excel workbook

Tags: excel, wildcard, vba

I want to use a wildcard to open a workbook stored in the same folder as my macro workbook. In the folder is a file named `302113-401yr-r01.xlsm`. Here is my code:

```
Workbooks.Open filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\302113*.xlsm"
```

However, it tells me that there is no such file. Any advice?

Comment: you can't use asterisk in path or file name. You need to open each file separately. Search for 'Dir function' here in SO, there are lots of examples for sure. [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779%28v=office.14%29.aspx) you find some information, too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We cannot open a file using a wildcard - imagine the chaos if we could!

You'll need to use `Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\302113*.xlsm")` to loop through the files that this returns. If there will only be one then just use this function once:

```
Dim sFound As String

sFound = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\302113*.xlsm")    'the first one found
If sFound <> "" Then
    Workbooks.Open filename:= ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFound
End If
```

[Dir Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php) :tech on the net

Comment: + 1 `We cannot open a file using a wildcard - imagine the chaos if we could!` So True :)

Comment: Ah, I see how opening a file using wildcards would be problematic. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Just one comment, unless I'm mistaken, it seems that the DIR Function only returns the filename, not the path and file name. So when I use Workbooks.Open in the above code, I had to put use:  ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFound

Comment: Thanks for posting back, I've added this to the answer, in case someone else finds it useful.

Comment: I don't understand why the comment `the chaos` seems every other programming language supports wildcards, it's up to the coder to code the logic, not the language.

Comment: If it were made easy to open files, from whatever application, based on wildcard matching (regex), then the simplest user-error (or even coder-error) could cause hundreds, perhaps thousands!, of files to  start opening. (We could still implement such a feature if we really wanted to.)

Answer (score 3):

From my experience this works if you have the wildcard/asterix as the last symbol in the string and if there is only one file. Try doing:

```
Workbooks.Open filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\302113*"
```

For example I am using:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="X:\business\2014\Easy*"
```

and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can open files using the wildcard, but only with UNC paths for some reason.

For example :

```
Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open("\\yourServerHere\dataAutomation\*.xlsx")
```

Comment: This approach does not work for me, cancel my upvote ( it's locked).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that experienced yet with Excel but the following works well for me for using wildcards in filenames to open files.  This example requires all files to be in the same directory/folder.  Yes, it is pretty simplistic.

```
Sub using_wildcards_to_open_files_in_excel_vba()

    Dim mypath As String
    Dim sFilename As String

    'Suppose you have three files in a folder
    ' Named blank.xlsx,, ex1_939_account.xlsx,  and ex1_opt 5.xlsx

    'Manually open the blank.xlsx file

    'The following code lines will open the second two files before closing the previously opened file.

    ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    mypath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    'opening xlsx file with name containing "939" and closing current file
    mypath = mypath & "\*939*.xlsx"
    'MsgBox mypath  'Checking
    sFilename = Dir(mypath)
    'MsgBox sFilename  'Checking

    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFilename

    ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    mypath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    'opening xlsx file with name ending in "opt 5" and closing current file
    mypath = mypath & "\*opt 5.xlsx"
    'MsgBox mypath  'Checking
    sFilename = Dir(mypath)
    'MsgBox sFilename  'Checking

    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFilename

End Sub
```