# Import CSV file with partial name into excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv, import

I've got many CSV files and I want to use macro to import them (and manipulate them) into a existing excel file.

The thing is that I only know a part of the files. They are like :

- "ThisIsTheFirstFile-01234564893.csv"
- "ThisIsTheSecondFile-015648942314.csv" ...

So I used this code to import my file :

```
Sub LoadFromFile()
    Dim fileName As String, folder As String

    folder = "C:\FolderPath\"
    fileName = "ThisIsTheFirstFile-*"

    Dim file As String
    file = Dir$(folder & fileName & ".*")

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("A1").Select

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
        .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & file, Destination:=ActiveCell)
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

But it doesn't seem to match the filename. For now I just wish to load one file, I'll then manipulate it, exctract data, supress all data loaded to load others files after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527673/2707864), `file` will only contain the file name, you have to concatenate the folder.