# Possible to use a wild card for the extension?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to use a wild card for a file extension?

```
ImageDir = CurrentProject.Path & "\Images\Invitory Items\" & Me.ListInvent.Column(1, r) & ".*"
```

The above is not working. Google doesn't offer much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a wildcard to open an excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527415/using-a-wildcard-to-open-an-excel-workbook)

Comment: One line of code and "not working" isn't much to go on.

Comment: @TimWilliams There is not much to it. Just trying to find a way to reference a file that could have any number of file types. (E.g: .jpg, .png, .ico, .gif, ect...)

Answer (score 0):

```
iDir = Dir(CurrentProject.Path & "\Images\InvitoryItems\" & Me.ListInvent.Column(1, r) & ".*")
ImageDir = CurrentProject.Path & "\Images\InvitoryItems\" & iDir
```