# ThisWorkbook.Path

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub a()

    Dim copy_range As Variant
  
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/* (2).csv")
    copy_range = Sheets(1).Range("A1:C288").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
    Sheets(2).Range("A1:C288") = copy_range
    
   
      
End Sub
```

In this part Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/* (2).csv")

It says the file doesn't exist.

The current folder contains (2) to (19).csv .
The full name of the file name is
20222022(2).csv
20222022(3).csv
~
20222022(19).csv
no see.

The folder path is like this.
C:\Users\fauus\Desktop\람세스 제어반

Comment: `Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/* (2).csv")` is missing an ampersand, has a `*` instead of a `"`. And the path separator is wrong if on Windows.

Comment: I'm a Korean. Can you upload the finished version?
The full name of the file name is
20222022(2).csv
20222022(3).csv
~
20222022(19).csv
no see.

Comment: `Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*" & "(2).csv")` for Windows. I don't use macs see help if you do https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function

Comment: I applied as you suggested, but the result is the same.

Comment: Dir() only returns the *filename*, so if the current directory isn't `ThisWorkbook.Path` it won't find the file.

Comment: Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\* (2).csv")

Comment: I used all methods.
But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the DIR and you slash is the wrong way round, the following should work:

```
Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*(2).csv"
```

Comment: You can't pass wildcards to `Open()`

Comment: Yes you can, wildcard worked fine when I ran the code myself

Comment: I do see some disagreement here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527415/using-a-wildcard-to-open-an-excel-workbook  Did not work for me in testing though.

Answer (score 0):

`Dir()` only returns the file *name*, not the full path, so if the current directory isn't `ThisWorkbook.Path` it won't find the file.

```vb
Sub a()

    Dim copy_range As Variant, f, fldr As String, wb As Workbook

    fldr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    f = Dir(fldr & "* (2).csv", vbNormal)

    If Len(f) > 0 Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fldr & f)
        copy_range = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C288").Value
        wb.Close
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:C288") = copy_range
    Else
        MsgBox "No file found!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I used the code you provided.
But nothing changes.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path` give you?  Is it a local folder, network folder, or some type of http:// path (SharePoint/OneDrive/etc) ?

Comment: C:\Users\fauus\Desktop\람세스 제어반

This is the path to the folder you are actually using.